# How to connect desktop to box-type tv through IPTV Set-Top box with HDMI cable

Tags: display, hdmi, desktop-computer, tv

I have an old box-type tv, desktop, iptv set-top box and HDMI cable. The iptv connects to the tv with red,white,yellow cables, and it also has HDMI port. So, I tried to connect pc to the iptv with HDMI cable since the iptv is connected to tv. But it don't work. Unlike hdtv, my tv is old, it doesn't have a VGA port so I can't directly connect it. What I have missed? Could you guys help me to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: What make model is the 'iptv'? Most likely the HDMI is out not in on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to connect your desktop and old box-type tv, you just need a converter from HDMI to AV. From my understanding for "IPTV" is controlled by telecom carrier, you need check with them.